# Error while sending email to Multiple Addresses From MYSQL Database using PHP

Tags: php, arrays, email, variables, recordset

I am trying to send an email to multiple email addresses which are contained in a database and sorted into a recordset... The recordset has multiple columns, but I only need one: "Email". I know that if I have them in an array I can implode them and separate them by commas, but I'm not sure how I could do that with a recordset column. Anyone know how?  BTW I know I have the mail function commented out...  The echo is returning null...

**Heres the code that I tried:**

```
    $colname_rsAllLeads = "-1";
if (isset($_SESSION['MM_Username'])) {
  $colname_rsAllLeads = $_SESSION['MM_Username'];
}
mysql_select_db($database_myBackOfficeConn, $myBackOfficeConn);
$query_rsAllLeads = sprintf("SELECT Email FROM Leads WHERE `User` = %s ORDER BY FullName ASC", GetSQLValueString($colname_rsAllLeads, "text"));
$rsAllLeads = mysql_query($query_rsAllLeads, $myBackOfficeConn) or die(mysql_error());
$row_rsAllLeads = mysql_fetch_assoc($rsAllLeads);
$totalRows_rsAllLeads = mysql_num_rows($rsAllLeads);



$editFormAction = $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];
if (isset($_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'])) {
  $editFormAction .= "?" . htmlentities($_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']);
} 

if ((isset($_POST["MM_insert"])) && ($_POST["MM_insert"] == "form")) {

    $startcode = $_POST['messagefield'];
    $replaced = preg_replace( '/\\\\(?="|\')/', '', $startcode );
    echo $replaced;
    $collectedleads = implode(',', $row_rsAllLeads['Email']);
    echo $collectedleads;

    /*
 $to = $collectedleads;
 $subject = $_POST['subjectfield'];
 $body = $replaced;
 $headers = "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n"; 
 $headers .= "Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1\r\n"; 
 $headers .= "From: " . $row_rs_CurrentUser['FirstName'] . " " . $row_rs_CurrentUser['LastName'] . " <" . $row_rs_CurrentUser['Email'] . ">";
 if (mail($to, $subject, $body, $headers)) {
  } else {
   echo("<p>Message delivery failed...</p>");
  }
  */

  $insertSQL = sprintf("INSERT INTO PendingEmails (`to`, subject, message) VALUES (%s, %s, %s)",
                       GetSQLValueString($row_rsAllLeads['Email'], "text"),
                       GetSQLValueString($_POST['subjectfield'], "text"),
                       GetSQLValueString($_POST['messagefield'], "text"));

  mysql_select_db($database_myBackOfficeConn, $myBackOfficeConn);
  $Result1 = mysql_query($insertSQL, $myBackOfficeConn) or die(mysql_error());

  $insertGoTo = "Email Sent.php";
  if (isset($_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'])) {
    $insertGoTo .= (strpos($insertGoTo, '?')) ? "&" : "?";
    $insertGoTo .= $_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'];
  }
  header(sprintf("Location: %s", $insertGoTo));
}
```

When I use `var_dump($row_rsAllLeads['Email'])` it outputs **string(16) "acorso@gmail.com"**  but I know that there is no error in my SQL query because when I put them in a select box, they all show up...

Comment: Don't use mail() and don't build your own mime messages. mail() is absolute CRAP for figuring out what's going wrong. use PHPMailer or Swiftmailer. Then check your SMTP server's logs to see why mails are being rejected.

Comment: The mail isnt getting rejected...  I have it commented out...  The problem is im trying to separate a recordset by commas and its not working...

Comment: Then why all that string fiddling when you've already got an array of addresses? `$list = implode($address_array);` and done.

Comment: Because, its not an array, its a string...

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, it seems you are getting only the first row from the result. So you have to get all of them:

```
$collectedleads = array();

while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($rsAllLeads)) {
   $collectedleads[] = $row['Email'];
}
```

After that you have to separate each email address with a `comma`. 
Try using [implode](http://php.net/manual/bg/function.implode.php) method:

```
$collectedleads = implode(',', $collectedleads);
echo $collectedleads;
```

Comment: Im getting this error: Warning: implode() [function.implode]: Invalid arguments passed in /home/content/06/9464206/html/BackOffice/Send Broadcast.php on line 106

Comment: What returns `$row_rsAllLeads['Email']`? Check with `var_dump($row_rsAllLeads['Email']);` and paste the result on your first post, please.

Comment: Never Mind its string(16) "acorso@gmail.com"

Comment: You have only one email address and you don't want something additional to send the mail. If you have more than one email you have to separate each one with comma.

Comment: I have over 100 email adresses in the recordset!  Its only showing one, and I tried using implode to separate but it still shows one!

Comment: Then your SQL query is not returning the proper result. Check it firstly.

Comment: I think the problem is that $row_rsAllLeads['Email'] isnt an array!  Or is it?

Comment: And if not, how do I make it one?

Comment: It is not an array. It is a string, as you can see when using `var_dump`. Implode is for arrays, so you can't use it in this situation.

Comment: It is still returning one, but I know that it works because if I put the variable in a select box, they all show up...  So what am I doing wrong?

Comment: I don't know. Couldn't help anymore without knowing how your code is working. I edited my answer and when you get all the emails you can use one of these methods to get the recipients string. It seems you get only the first email, so maybe you have to get all of them with a `while` loop or something like that.